# How to update base image of many microservices

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

I currently have 50+ microservices running on mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim each of these microservices has its own git repository and its own dockerfile referencing this image.

Is there a best practice/method for monitoring the public repository for new releases of the microsoft base image and then automatically updating the dockerfiles for all these applications?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure Container Registry, it provide ACR Tasks that can be used to automate the scenario you're looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tutorial-base-image-update

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.